# Got ProvisionedThroughputExceededException error when I'm trying to write 100,000 records

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I've encountered `The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API` following error message, when I'm trying to write 100,000 records in Dynamodb. I've used `BatchWriteItem` to insert data to Dynamodb database by 1,000 records after 1,000.

And, when I'm trying to increase `Maximum provisioned capacity` for both Read and Write, it showing capacity should not be more than 40,000 as per image. Please let me know how to solve that issue, thanks.
[image]

Comment: A bunch of ideas for dealing with that problem [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=provisionedthroughputexceededexception+dynamodb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution that we need to add `maxRetries` and `retryDelayOptions` options when we configure DynamoDB like:

```
let dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
    apiVersion: '2012-08-10',
    region: 'ap-southeast-1,
    maxRetries: 13,
    retryDelayOptions: {
        base: 200
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best course of action is to insert an intentional delay into your loop (the loop that "[tries to] write 100,000 records in Dynamodb"). If after each `BatchWriteItem` your program/thread will sleep for several seconds you will spread your writes along a longer time period, effectively reducing the (per second) capacity needed to handle them.

Alternatively, you can also try to use [on demand mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.OnDemand). Note however, that with this mode it becomes harder to predict your financial cost. However, if this write operation is a one time thing, you can switch to this mode temporarily.

Comment: Your solution is also workable. But I've found solution already.